# PHP How to echo a 3-dim array

Tags: php, arrays, iteration, echo

After searching for an answer in this forum I found only related questions but under other context that would not apply to my case. Here's my problem:

I have a 3-dim array defined in a function like this:

```
$m_Array[h][$family][$iterator]
```

the values for

```
$family range from 6-10;

$iterator from 0-3 but has duplicates (0,1,2,3,1),

and the  $m_Array results in values (25,26,30,31,33).
```

I am unable to echo the result using those indices to get these results once returned from the function.
NOTE: I was able to echo when I had 2-dim $m_Array[h][$iterator] but could not use it because the last value for the iterator would replace the second in the array.
Since I was able to echo the 2-dim, this is not a question on getting the return from the function or iterate over the indices.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by echo? you just want to just show the array in the screen? why not just do var_dump()?

Comment: loop your foeach loop you will get d answer...Eg : foreach within a foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as others mentioned, you can use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`. If you need to access each item then you're going to need nested loops.

```
foreach($m_Array as $i => $h)
{
     //echo $i, $key for h
     foreach($h as $j => $family)
     {
          //echo $j, key for family
          foreach($family as $k => $iterator)
          {
                echo $iterator;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `print_r($arrayName)` to print an array. You cannot `echo` an Array or Object

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$keys = array_keys($h);
for($i = 0; $i < count($h); $i++) {
    echo $keys[$i] . "{<br>";
    foreach($h[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
    }
    echo "}<br>";
}
```

It prints all values and keys